# mapbox_gl map tile starts in top left corner

Tags: flutter, android-studio, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm having an issue with mapbox_gl where every page I load one of their maps onto appears in the top left corner of the page. Shouldn't this appear in the center? When you tap home and then come back to the page the map is centered where it should belong though.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 300.0,
            height: 200.0,
            child: MapboxMap(
              accessToken: MapsDemo.ACCESS_TOKEN,
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(-33.852, 151.211),
                zoom: 11.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextButton(
                          child: const Text('add'),
                          onPressed: (_circleCount == 12) ? null : _add,
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          child: const Text('remove'),
                          onPressed: (_selectedCircle == null) ? null : _remove,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextButton(
                          child: const Text('change circle-opacity'),
                          onPressed: (_selectedCircle == null)
                              ? null
                              : _changeCircleOpacity,
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          child: const Text('change circle-radius'),
                          onPressed: (_selectedCircle == null)
                              ? null
                              : _changeCircleRadius,
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          child: const Text('change circle-color'),
                          onPressed: (_selectedCircle == null)
                              ? null
                              : _changeCircleColor,
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          child: const Text('change circle-blur'),
                          onPressed: (_selectedCircle == null)
                              ? null
                              : _changeCircleBlur,
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          child: const Text('change circle-stroke-width'),
                          onPressed: (_selectedCircle == null)
                              ? null
                              : _changeCircleStrokeWidth,
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          child: const Text('change circle-stroke-color'),
                          onPressed: (_selectedCircle == null)
                              ? null
                              : _changeCircleStrokeColor,
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          child: const Text('change circle-stroke-opacity'),
                          onPressed: (_selectedCircle == null)
                              ? null
                              : _changeCircleStrokeOpacity,
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          child: const Text('change position'),
                          onPressed: (_selectedCircle == null)
                              ? null
                              : _changePosition,
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          child: const Text('toggle draggable'),
                          onPressed: (_selectedCircle == null)
                              ? null
                              : _changeDraggable,
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          child: const Text('get current LatLng'),
                          onPressed:
                              (_selectedCircle == null) ? null : _getLatLng,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

[the map should be placed over the mapbox text not off in the left corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKmxs.png)

[After pressing home and reopening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B6Li.png)

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I config the mapbox_gl in the pubspech of the next form:
mapbox_gl: 0.14.0
mapbox_gl_web: 0.14.0
This works for me.
I hope it serves you or someone else, this on the date of this answer.